# Miscalculation of Lagrange interpolation formula for higher degree

Tags: c, double, overflow, interpolation, numeric

I am approximating Runge’s function using Lagrange’s interpolation formula for 50 interpolation points. I have written the following program to do this, but I am getting the wrong value for x= -0.992008. That wrong value is  4817543.091313, but it should be 5197172.55933613. I have got this value from the following link: [Link](https://atozmath.com/CONM/NumeInterPola.aspx?q=LI&q1=1%60-1.000000%2C-0.960000%2C-0.920000%2C-0.880000%2C-0.840000%2C-0.800000%2C-0.760000%2C-0.720000%2C-0.680000%2C-0.640000%2C-0.600000%2C-0.560000%2C-0.520000%2C-0.480000%2C-0.440000%2C-0.400000%2C-0.360000%2C-0.320000%2C-0.280000%2C-0.240000%2C-0.200000%2C-0.160000%2C-0.120000%2C-0.080000%2C-0.040000%2C0.000000%2C0.040000%2C0.080000%2C0.120000%2C0.160000%2C0.200000%2C0.240000%2C0.280000%2C0.320000%2C0.360000%2C0.400000%2C0.440000%2C0.480000%2C0.520000%2C0.560000%2C0.600000%2C0.640000%2C0.680000%2C0.720000%2C0.760000%2C0.800000%2C0.840000%2C0.880000%2C0.920000%2C0.960000%2C1.000000%600.038462%2C0.041597%2C0.045126%2C0.049116%2C0.053648%2C0.058824%2C0.064767%2C0.071633%2C0.079618%2C0.088968%2C0.100000%2C0.113122%2C0.128866%2C0.147929%2C0.171233%2C0.200000%2C0.235849%2C0.280899%2C0.337838%2C0.409836%2C0.500000%2C0.609756%2C0.735294%2C0.862069%2C0.961538%2C1.000000%2C0.961538%2C0.862069%2C0.735294%2C0.609756%2C0.500000%2C0.409836%2C0.337838%2C0.280899%2C0.235849%2C0.200000%2C0.171233%2C0.147929%2C0.128866%2C0.113122%2C0.100000%2C0.088968%2C0.079618%2C0.071633%2C0.064767%2C0.058824%2C0.053648%2C0.049116%2C0.045126%2C0.041597%2C0.038462%23%60-0.992008%60LI%601&dp=12&do=1#PrevPart) The code used are as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double
runge(double x)
{
    return (1 / (1 + (25 * x * x)));
}

double
ab(double x)
{
    if (x < 0)
        return -1 * x;
    return x;
}

double
lag_func(double x, double *y_i, double *x_i, int n)
{
    double ex = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        double numer = 1.0,
            denom = 1.0,
            prod = 1.0;

        for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
            if (i != j) {
                numer = (x - x_i[j]);
                denom = (x_i[i] - x_i[j]);
                prod *= numer / denom;
            }
        }
        ex += (prod) * y_i[i];
    }
    return ex;
}

int
main()
{
    int n;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    double y_i[n + 1],
     x_i[n + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
        x_i[i] = ((2 * (double) i) / (double) n) - 1;
        y_i[i] = runge(x_i[i]);
    }

    printf("%lf\n", lag_func(-0.992008, y_i, x_i, n));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including code that anybody can compile and execute without any changes or additions and include an exact copy of the input needed to reproduce the issue, an exact copy of the output observed, and a description of the output desired instead. The code currently in the question is missing at least one `#include` and is missing a definition of `runge`.

Comment: `i =0 ;i<=n`  You sure?

Comment: @stark: Yes. There is a polynomial of degree n. The terms run from exponent 0 to exponent n, inclusive.

Answer (score 3):

The web site is rounding its Runge coefficients to six digits. Given the magnitudes of the terms involved, up to 3.9978•10<sup>11</sup>, this introduces multiple errors up to around 2•10<sup>5</sup>.

This can be seen by inserting `y_i[i] = round(y_i[i] * 1e6) / 1e6;` after `y_i[i] = runge(x_i[i]);`. Then the output of the program is 5197172.558199, matching the web site’s inaccurate result.

The web site is wrong; the result of the code in the question is better.

Comment: There is no Runge-Kutta here, I'm not sure if the Runge function, a counter-example for the usefulness of polynomial interpolation, is named for the Carl of the (first?) third order numerical ODE integration method, or someone else. What you are rounding are the function values of the Runge function. One could additionally also round the `x_i` or the values of the Lagrangian kernel functions.

Comment: @LutzLehmann: Thanks, updated. Just habit, I can’t type “Runge” without typing “Runge-Kutta” and fixing it afterward.